# What is IndividualId and MasterRecordId?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, individual

So I've set up Marketing Cloud Connect between my Marketing Cloud instance to my Sales Cloud instance. Then I went to Contact Builder > Data Sources, and then proceeded to "Set up object" on my Lead object.

In that Lead fields option, I notice there are certain fields where it auto-ticked to sync like so:

[image: SFMC Synchronized Lead Fields]

1. What is Individual Id and MasterRecordID?
2. I can only add Invididual in the Lead page layout but not MasterRecord?
3. Why is it required field in SFMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adrian's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/357150/2984) goes into what they are, but I'll address the rest.

> I can only add Invididual in the Lead page layout but not MasterRecord?

The MasterRecordId field is really only useful when you merge records together; the record with a MasterRecordId set will end up in the Recycle Bin. This can only be done with a "merge record" API call, though, which MC will never do, as far as I'm aware. It's safe to ignore this field. You can't add it to the layout, because it would serve no purpose, as any record with this field set has already been deleted.

The IndividualId field links multiple records to the same Data Protection and Privacy record (e.g. so they can opt out of emails or phone calls across multiple instances). You don't need to worry about this field directly, nor does it need to be on a page layout, though you can choose to do so if you like.

> Why is it required field in SFMC?

It's required for proper software functionality. But you don't need to worry about this yourself, it's handled for you. Feel free to ignore those fields, as they don't have any particular significance to you unless you need them for a specific purpose.

Comment: I love how you just know the answer to these esoteric questions

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on `IndividualId`:

> **Description**
> ID of the data privacy record associated with this lead. This field is available if you enabled Data Protection and Privacy in Setup.)

And `MasterRecordId`:

> **Description**
> If this record was deleted as the result of a merge, this field contains the ID of the record that was kept. If this record was deleted for any other reason, or has not been deleted, the value is null.